# Use of として in sentence about conditionals

Tags: grammar, parsing, conditionals

I was reading up on the use of conditionals と, ば, たら and なら. One part of [the source](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17223/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89) talks about one type of conditional clause, but I am not sure of its meaning.

Here's what the source says, and my attempt at translation:

> 仮定条件(前件が仮に成立した場合、その前件を条件**として**後件が成立することを表わす)
>
> Assumptive conditional clauses (the first half of the sentence (conditional clause) is based on an assumption; expresses the first half as a requirement for the establishment of the other half)

The word として is confusing me. [There have been other questions about として](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14719/meaning-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-in-this-sentence), but reading the sentence above with an "as" or a "by way of" does not make sense to me. Easy sentences are okay, like:

> 彼は医者**として**有名だ。He is famous as a doctor.
>
> (医者**として**有名 = Famous as doctor)

However, how do I parse this more complicated sentence?

> {[その前件を 条件**として**後件が] 成立すること} を 表わす
>
> 条件**として**後件 = The latter as the requirement?

Comment: Why doesn't "as" make sense here? It makes perfect sense. If I have something like 「ｘになれば・・後件」 then the 前件 here is the conditional. It basically means the former is used as a condition, and the latter part is the result.

Comment: @strawberry jam but where does the word "result" come in? I only see 前件, 条件, 後件. What's more, the last two terms are jammed between 前件 and 成立すること, which I can't wrap my head around...

Comment: 後件 means "consequent"

Comment: darn, i always thought 前件 and 後件 were former and latter...
so 条件として後件 means the consequent as the condition...?

Comment: will think about it and post my findings at a later time.

Comment: その前件を。。として. So it's the former as a condition. By the way, former and latter = 後者 and 前者.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the sentence "If I were a doctor, I would cure his sickness."

"If I were a doctor" is a hypothesis(前件), "I would cure his sickness" is a consequent(後件).

その前件を条件として、後件が成立する means  " The hypothesis (come into effect) as a condition(条件), and the consequent come into effect."

Comment: Thank you, the " 、" was helpful. I was trying to fit the 前件を with 成立する. "A を B とする/として" is something new to me. Perhaps 彼が医者として有名だ is 彼を医者として有名だ? Reference: http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%92%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%92%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-oto-suruoto-shite/

Comment: 彼を医者として有名だ is unnatural because を有名だ is unnatural.but 彼を医者として尊敬している is natural because を尊敬している is natural.

Comment: hmm... from your reply, I gather that 前件を does link with 成立する (the hypothesis comes into effect as 条件), but 後件が also links with 成立する (the consequent comes into effect)

Comment: I just add "comes into effect" to "the hypothesis" to be understood easily.